# How to write jasmine test case for ngDialog in angular Js?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have code lines in my controller. Let me know how to write jasmine test case for this?

```html
 if(!angular.element('#reimsave').hasClass("pointerEvent") && !angular.element('#reimedit').is(':visible'))
                    {
                        ngDialog.openConfirm({
                            template: 'app/shared/views/confirmAlert.html',
                            scope: $scope,
                            closeByDocument: false,
                            closeByEscape:false
                        }).then(function (value) {
                            intial = slected;
                            $scope.selectedTab = 'earnings';
                            $location.path( "/directDeposit/earnings" );
                        }, function (error) {
                        });
                    }
```

Comment: No Answer for this question?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to test exactly.

One way of testing could be...

```
it("should call ngDialog.openConfirm"), function() {
  spyOn(ngDialog, 'openConfirm').and.callThrough();

  //include whatever code you need here to meet your if condition

  expect(ngDialog.openConfirm).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

I have not been able to test anything in the dialog itself though as in my test runner, the dialog does not actually popup!